# Can someone give a regex expression for the below condition react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, validation, expression

Spaces

- Will only be allowed within the alpha text
- Multiple spaces will be allowed within the field but cannot be consecutive

Dashes

- Will only be allowed within the alpha text  (boyd-lawson" or "boyd - lawson" is ok, but "boyd-" and "boyd " and " "-boyd" is not)
- Multiple dashes will be allowed within the field but cannot be consecutive

Periods

- Cannot be the first character in the field
- Multiple periods will be allowed within the field but cannot be consecutive

Apostrophes

- Multiple apostrophes will be allowed within the field but cannot be consecutive

I tried using the below expression
`/^(?!.*(?:\s\s|-{2,}|\.{2,}|'{2,}))(?=[A-Za-z\s.\-']+$)(?!.*(?:^\.))/g`

Comment: you can use chatGPT for this purpose

Comment: @JamshaidTariq, this is a very bad advice. ChatGPT doesn't understand what it does in general, and regexes in particular. And its output would hardly be of any value for OP.

Comment: @Markalex , you may be right. but couple of days ago, I asked for regex from ChatGPT to validate string for `Python Variable naming conditions`. ChatGPT gave me regex and It was perfect.

Comment: @JamshaidTariq, that simply means, that you could google the same regex.

Comment: yeah if someone has written regex for exact same requirements but what if some custom requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression which attempts to refactor your requirements into one single definition.

- The first character cannot be dash, space, or period.
- Within the text, a character can be any non-dash, non-space, non-period, non-apostrophe character, or a dash, space, period, or apostrophe if it is not immediately followed by another.
- The last character cannot be dash, space, period, or apostrophe.

To permit a single-character field, the expression after the first character is optional.

We separately have to prohibit two adjacent apostrophes at the beginning or end using lookarounds.

```
/^(?!'')[^- .](([^- .']|[- .'][^- .'])*[^- .])?(?<!'')$/
```

You might want to restrict `[^- .]` and `[^- .']` further if you specifically require these characters to be strictly alphanumeric. For example, the above formulation will permit two adjacent commas or circumflexes; maybe you want to require actual text, or add some other further constraints.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
const pattern = /^(?!.*--)(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*[^\w\s]\s+)(?!.*\s[^\w\s])(?!.*\.\s)(?!.*\s\.)(?!.*'\s)(?!.*\s')(?!.*[^\w\s-]\s+)(?!.*\s[^\w\s-])(?!.*-\s)(?!.*\s-)[A-Za-z0-9\s.-]*[A-Za-z0-9]$/;
```

Comment: Thanks Vinod, but error message is being triggered for more than 2 characters and validation not working as expected.

Comment: @ManojGowda, try it now, when correct formatting is applied and all symbols are seen. And and advice for you and answerer for future: look into [how to format post](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It will make understanding of your questions/answers easier.